# Auto fill insert form with $_GET data

Tags: php, html, cakephp-1.2

I have a search form, where the user can insert in the same field the name of one or more authors. 
I have this code:

```
Author<br /><input type="text" name="autore" value=<?php echo $_GET['autore'] ?> ><br/>
```

To automatically fill the Author field on the next page.
My problem is that if the user writes for example:

```
san, gli, tro
```

In the Author field I'll get only 'san,' , while I want 'san, gli, tro' . 
How can I solve this?

Comment: You have quoted two of the HTML attributes. Why not consider that for the one where it's important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you do:

```
Author<br /><input type="text" name="autore" value="<?php echo $_GET['autore'] ?>" ><br/>
```

(Notice quotes around the *value* attribute)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around value from php. Like this:

```
Author<br /><input type="text" name="autore" value="<?php echo $_GET['autore'] ?>" ><br/>
```

In your case the final html will be

```
Author<br /><input type="text" name="autore" value=san gli tro ><br/>
```

so the value of attribute `value` is `san` and the other to are empty attribute names.

With quotes, the final html will be

```
Author<br /><input type="text" name="autore" value="san, gli, tro" ><br/>
```

Which is what you need.